# How to prevent jquery ajax from following 302 redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery ajax to connect to URL and the URL will return a 302 redirect. I need the ajax request to not follow the redirect but I want to get the URL of the redirect from the `content-location` header.

I have this code which gets the contents of the header but it also follows the redirect. I need it not to follow the redirect because it redirects to a one time use only URL so even though i have the URL it is useless because it has already been 'used'.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url1,
    success: function(data, textStatus, request){
        var sdurl = request.getResponseHeader('content-location');
        finishedfunction(url1, url2, sdurl);
    },
    error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var sdurl = request.getResponseHeader('content-location');
        finishedfunction(url1, url2, sdurl);
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: I can't edit any of the server code.

Comment: Plenty of previous questions on this, and the answer is always 'No, following a redirect is part of the XMLHttpRequest spec and will always happen silently'.

Comment: perhaps you could use your own server to proxy the request for you

Comment: At least in supporting browsers, you can use [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) for this. [It has an option to disable following](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/redirect).